# JSBIN doesn't load in reveal.js presentation

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, jsbin

When using multiple jsbin embeds in a presentation, each bin doesn't load until I click one of the headers (ie, "HTML", "CSS", etc.).  This only seems to happen in larger presentations like [this](http://mkfreeman.github.io/gh590/lecture1t/#/) one (navigate to [/3/4](http://mkfreeman.github.io/gh590/lecture1t/#/3/4) from the start to see the unloaded embed). I tried running the code mentioned [here](http://jsbin.com/help/embed-doesnt-load) without success:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), function (iframe) {
  try {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('jsbin:refresh', '*');
  }
  catch(err){
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is waiting to go live in the morning UK time: https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/commit/6ba04d0697084a7a25b06bd7d76cbf74b4556f19

It was a problem with the visibility of the panels in jsbin that needed resetting once the iframe comes in to view.